# Play Sounds when user clicks on the Radio Button! FLASH AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, radio-button

Using a radio button for a quiz game, i want a buzz sound when the user gets it wrong when clicking on the radio button. How do i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? This link might help: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html

Answer (score 0):

You can load the sound and play it using the Sound class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html

To get it to play when you click on the radio button, you could add a listener to the radio button to check for when the user has clicked on it, then check which answer they clicked and play the sound if needed.

RadioButton class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/RadioButton.html